# Change name attribute of symfony 2 form field

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

I have a form to register :

```
 public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    parent::buildForm($builder, $options);

    $builder->add('tel');
    $builder->add('telvisible');
}
```

after the display of this field:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="fos_user_registration_form_telvisible" name="fos_user_registration_form[telvisible]" value="1">
```

But I want to be displayed:

```
  <input type="checkbox" id="fos_user_registration_form_telvisible" name="telvisible" value="1">
```

Comment: Why do you want to change the attribute?

Comment: Basically you can't control the name.  The S2 form handle relies on it to map your posted data back to your entities.  And once you start making more complex forms with nested entities then the names get completely out of control.  It all works but it's not meant to be human readable.

Comment: And the issue about the name is...?

Comment: i have problem with jquery plugin :unrecognized expression: input[name=fos_user_registration_form[telvisible]] 
but when i use other name (without [])  is working successfully

Comment: That is a well known javascript/php issue.  In most cases, you can fix it by surrounding the name with quotes.   input[name='fos_user_registration_form[telvisible]']

Comment: I think this is a valid question. I'm creating an API and wish to change the name. Ideally I would want my API interface to be as much human readable as possible.

Answer (score 2):

To remove type name from the name you have good two solutions:

1. Return null in your `getName` or `getBlockPrefix` implementation.

> ```
> public function getBlockPrefix() 
> {
>     return null;
> }
> ```

2. Create the form using createNamed method.

   > ```
   > $form = $this->get('form.factory')
   >  ->createNamedBuilder(null, 'form', $address)
   >  ->add('address', 'text');
   > ```